# gethostname on a machine with multiple network interfaces

Tags: c++, windows, networking

What will the gethostname system call return on a machine with multiple network interfaces? Is it possible to configure this at the OS level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of network interfaces used to connect the machine to the world is more or less independent of the number of host names. You can have multiple interfaces with a single name (even though it's somewhat unusual) or multiple names with a single interface (considerably more common).

As to what value it does return, MSDN says:

> f the gethostname function is used on a cluster resource on Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2003, or Windows 2000 Server and the _CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_ environment variable is defined, then the value in this environment variable overrides the actual hostname and is returned. On a cluster resource, the _CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_ environment variable contains the name of the cluster.
>
> The gethostname function queries namespace providers to determine the local host name using the SVCID_HOSTNAME GUID defined in the Svgguid.h header file. If no namespace provider responds, then the gethostname function returns the NetBIOS name of the local computer.

As such, it's normally a question of DNS configuration, but for a member of a cluster you can set an environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Assume that the machine has multiple interfaces each with different names, which amongst these names would be returned? Is there a notion of setting one interface as primary?

Comment: @Raam: The main question still is open (IMHO) and I need to know the same thing. Why you marked it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/gethostnameman.html

there will be one hostname -> root name

Answer (score -1):

The Hostname is stored at the OS Level .It doesn't matter how many NIC's your PC has, it will be the same for all of them.

Comment: The NETBIOS hostname is stored at the OSLevel. The GetHostName() first queries the DNS.